B&W sci-fi: crashed meteor that hypnotizes people that encounter it
It started off with a crashed meteor/asteroid/comet and whoever looked/touched it became hypnotized. I think it made a high pitched noise when someone would touch it.. In the middle of the movie I think I remember the main characters going to a gas station on a deserted road lined with trees. Near the end of the movie, two people became trapped in a barn/farm house where the hypnotized people (aliens) were building a ship. They tried to escape by using a revolving elevator. 
Can anyone name this film?

Do you remember if the aliens were peaceful or hostile?

Hostile. They were still people but in a trance from the meteor

That rules out the one I was thinking of.  It sounds almost like it could be It Came From Outer Space, since they're in trances, but in the long run, they turned out to be just trying to fix their ship and leave Earth.

It didnt take place in a desert, mostly a small town and farm fields from what I remember

Someone just found it for me! You were really close though, it ended up being "They Came from Outer Space" not "It" and apparently they are two entirely different movies. Anyways thanks so much for helping out!

I suggest you take a look at  "They Came From Beyond Space." 
Though not quite what you described, it does have mind control caused by squealing meteorites and an ending in a space center/industrial area. The aliens are also building spaceships. 

Omg thanks so much! This is it! :)

Could it be Stephen King's The Tommyknockers (1993) tv miniseries?
Essentially, a weird object is found in the woods and the towns folk start changing.  It turns out the object is an alien spaceship powering itself on the townsfolk.

The movie was made in the 1950s-1960's black & white, but the story line sounds the same, i remember watching it on youtube but forget the name :(

Sounds like It Came From Outer Space".
Only the young boy Bobby knows that the aliens are taking over the townsfolk to get them to repair their craft.
It is from 1953 and is set in the Midwest.

No, it didn't take place in a desert at all, it was in a farm field

It could be "Quatermass II" here is the trailer
From wikipedia:

The serial sees Professor Bernard Quatermass of the British Experimental Rocket Group being asked to examine strange meteorite showers. His investigations lead to his uncovering a conspiracy involving alien infiltration at the highest levels of the British Government. As even some of Quatermass's closest colleagues fall victim to the alien influence, he is forced to use his own unsafe rocket prototype, which recently caused a nuclear disaster at an Australian testing range, to prevent the aliens from taking over mankind.

It is a miniseries, but there is a film version. From the first episode there is a meteorite shower and some mind control:

Meteorites are falling over Southern England, one of which is observed by an Army radar unit. After a farmer finds one of the objects in a field, the soldiers become directly involved, and Captain Johnny Dillon decides to unofficially ask the father of his fiancée, Paula, to investigate.

Also, there is an industrial complex:

Quatermass agrees to accompany Dillon on an investigation and the pair visit the farmer, who refuses to talk and sends them away. At a pub, they find out that the nearby village of Winnerden Flats has been leveled to build an enormous industrial plant protected by armed guards, which is identical to Quatermass' moonbase design. Upon investigating a newly fallen meteorite, Dillon is sprayed from it with ammonia gas, and a distinctive mark appears on his face.


No, this wasn't it either. Its similar but I remember there not being any monsters/aliens in it, just the people under mind control, thanks for your help
